# web.xml not getting updated in eclipse juno

Tags: java, jboss, web.xml

Am using eclipse JUNO to run a simple "Helloworld" servlet and am using JBoss 7.1 as server..

Here is the code am running with

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;`
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and my web.xml is(even after running the servlet)

```
<display-name>bjp</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
<welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

means looking at this, it is clear that web.xml is not getting updated with the servlet information, like servlet mapping and servlet class..

Why web.xml is not getting updated with servlet class?? It works fine with Tomact..Please Help me

Comment: web.xml is (should) never be updated automatically. You must define servlet (and mappings) either in web.xml or you have to annotate it as required. Maybe I do not understand your question... What does 'it works fine with Tomcat' *exactly* mean?

Comment: Have you found solution to this? Mapping is also missing from my web.xml files generated from Eclipse Juno. specifically servlet, and servlet-mapping tags. if i add them manually everything works..

Answer (score 3):

Which version of the servlets you are using? if you are using Servlets3.0 then the servlets can be configured by `@WebServlet` annotation, so there is no need for `web.xml` configuration, that is the reason why Eclipse doesn't update `web.xml` file automatically when you create `servlet`. So you can have a code like this:

```
@WebServlet("/Hello")
public class Hello extends HttpServlet {
```

It will be do the same work as `web.xml` configuration will do.
If you still want to generate `web.xml` and dont want to use annotations then you have to change `version` while creating the dynamic web project from `3.0` to `2.5`.